# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'subscribe'

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a code to send a post to a broker and I've some problems. The code is below:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
def on_connect(self, client, userdata, rc):
    if rc==0:
    print("successful connection")
    client.subscribe("HelloWorld")
else:
    print("connection fail") #the subscriber will not receive the message

def on_message (client, userdata, msg):
print( str(msg.payload.decode('UTF-8'))) #Post Posted

client= mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect #Create the "client" object
client.on_message = on_message
client.username_pw_set("TypeUser",typePassaword) # I omitted username and password
client.connect('TypeURLBroker',TypePort) #Broker Online. 1º Termo: Url do broker; 2º Termo: Port
client.loop_start()

while 0==0:
mymsg='Hello World'
client.publish(topic='HelloWorld/', payload=mymsg)
```

Some errors appears and I don't have any idea to solve them. I need a little help.

List of errors:

```
successful connection
Exception in thread Thread-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\fvs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\fvs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fvs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 2606, in _thread_main
    self.loop_forever(retry_first_connection=True)
  File "C:\Users\fvs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 1470, in loop_forever
    rc = self.loop(timeout, max_packets)
  File "C:\Users\fvs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 995, in loop
    rc = self.loop_read(max_packets)
  File "C:\Users\fvs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 1273, in loop_read
    rc = self._packet_read()
  File "C:\Users\fvs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 1838, in _packet_read
    rc = self._packet_handle()
  File "C:\Users\fvs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 2291, in _packet_handle
    return self._handle_connack()
  File "C:\Users\fvs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 2349, in _handle_connack
    self.on_connect(self, self._userdata, flags_dict, result)
  File "C:/Users/fvs/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld.py", line 6, in on_connect
    client.subscribe("HelloWorld")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'subscribe'
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paho-mqtt) `on_connect` should have following signature

```
on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc)
```

You trying to use second positional argument, which in fact `userdata`, not `client`. Try

```
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc==0:
        print("successful connection")
        client.subscribe("HelloWorld")
    else:
        print("connection fail") #the subscriber will not receive the message
```

Comment: @Fábio Schreiber You are welcome) If answer was helpful you could mark it as right answer.